# Azure OAuth authentication from C# console application

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I want to login into `https://lcs.dynamics.com` from a C# console application.

When you navigate to lcs.dynamics.com, it redirects to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`

Here I enter a username as xyz@contoso.onmicrosoft.com and the password, system authenticates and redirects to lcs.dynamics.com

For this to work in my Azure Active Directory, I have created an Azure AD Web API application with the redirect URL as `https://lcs.dynamics.com`

I tried both approaches, creating a native application and authenticating using username and password as well as a Web API and authenticating using a secret key.

In both cases, I do receive an auth token which I parse as `Bearer <auth_token>` and set as the header value but when I make the `HttpRequest`, the response is still the login page instead of it moving ahead.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your requirement ? Do you want to login LCS using azure ad accounts ?

Comment: Yes, that is my requirement. I want to login to the LCS portal using my .onmicrosoft credentials

Comment: Are you trying to access data from the Dynamics API using the console application? This [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx) may help you authenticate.

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware of these APIs. I have no problem accessing Dynamics 365 data. I tried applying the same logic to access LCS but it simply doesnt work. I again am presented with the LCS login page even though I have acquired a token which I pass in the header.

Comment: Were you ever able ti get this working, @Zubair?  I am trying to do the same thing.